# .ADD examples to be used in Sybase Advantage Database Server

Tags: database, sybase, advantage-database-server

Im after an xx.ADD example database to run on a Sybase Advantage Database Server. cant find one, All help welcome,

Thanks,
Fox

Answer (score 1):

Just create one yourself.

The Advantage Data Architect that you can download from the ADS DevZone is the only tool I know that can create dictionaries (`.add`).

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=19&Product=8&Platform=6